# Acessing private structure pointer of base class in derived class function

Tags: c++

-----metaskill.hpp------

```
 typedef struct {
    predicate_func predicate;
    unsigned       enabled;
} frp_predicate;

class baseclass
{
   public:
   baseclass(void);
   frp_predicate **predicate()
   {
       return **mPredicates;
   }
   private:

   frp_predicate     **mPredicates;
};
class derivedclass:baseclass
{
   public:
   void init();
};
```

---

metaskill.cpp

```
#include "metaskill.hpp"
 baseclass::baseclass()
 {
    mPredicates=NULL;
 }
 void derivedclass::init()
 {
     /*private members cannot be accessed error comes
     so changed trying to access using public function of baseclass*/
   //mPredicates = new frp_predicate* [size+1];

    baseclass::predicate() = new frp_predicate* [10];    
 }
```

---

Here I have accessed the mPredicates which is a private member,I cant change it to protected or public.I have written a accessor function predicate to access the private member mPredicates of baseclass.But still i am getting error what did i made wrong here

Comment: Are you able to modify `baseclass`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access private members of a class directly outside member function of that class. That's the basic foundation of encapsulation.Although you can break encapsulation by using pointers.

Please put clarification as what your intention is?

Comment: I believe he wants to write an accessor for `mPredicates` in the derived class.